# it's possible to use sequences in mariaDB Server?

Tags: sql, syntax, mariadb, sequence, ddl

A sequence is an alternative to create for example the Primary Key on every record in your tables.

So this is the common syntax I'm using actually

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

As you can see the common solution I implemented is the `PRIMARY KEY` clausule

But is RDBMS such as Oracle or PostgreSQL is possible to use sequences for replacing the previous code

For example in Oracle you declare

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Or in PostgreSQL in this way

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

**But this is possible in mariaDB Server?**

Answer (score 4):

**In MariaDB since version 10.3 there is the possibility of natively using the creation of sequences; through the following example you can see how it is achieved**

First let's create the table sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id
START WITH 1
INCREASE BY 1;
```

If for example we want to see the structure of the table id, newly created; just execute the following in the console

```
MariaDB [blog]> describe id;
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| next_not_cached_value | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| minimum_value         | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| maximum_value         | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| start_value           | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| increment             | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cache_size            | bigint(21) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cycle_option          | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cycle_count           | bigint(21)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

From the above table you can notice important details such as the fact that the default numeric value is of type `BIGINT`

So that as we said that it is going to start in the numbering in 1 and in one more is going to increase, it allows us to generate the progressive number that can be associated, like a primary to a table

Let's create a new table of examples in the mariaDB manager

```
MariaDB [blog]> CREATE TABLE demo (
-> id BIGINT NOT NULL,
-> name VARCHAR (30),
-> PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Finally, when declaring a primary key of autoincrement type it is not necessary to declare it in the insert sentence, when we use a sequence if it is necessary to write the name of the column; as the following example

```
MariaDB [blog]> INSERT INTO demo (id, name)
-> VALUES
-> (NEXT VALUE FOR id, 'alpha');
```

How can the previous sequence be observed, to insert the dynamic value generated by the sequence, we invoke the name of the sequence through NEXT VALUE for and at the end the name of the sequence id

Finally, you can obtain the result of our previous sentence, we execute a SELECT regularly on the table and we obtain the following

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT * FROM demo;
+ ---- + ------ +
| id | name     |
+ ---- + ------ +
| 1 | alpha     |
+ ---- + ------ +
```

Extra configurations:

Optionally, you can configure the following parameters to a sequence within the mariaDB manager:

> 1. `minvalue` = You can set it 1
>
>    2. `maxvalue` = Depending on the type of data you choose if it is INT or `BIGINT` you must check to place a cap that respects the limits of
>         those data types
>    3. `Cycle` = By default it has the option no cycle, otherwise, once the minimum value starts and the maximum limit is reached, the counter
>         is restarted and the numbering begins again (provided that the limit
>         of the data type) possible )

Answer (score 2):

In a word - yes. That feature is available since version 10.3.

See [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-sequence/) for the full details.